# Why is the pointer blank when it refers to a value of zero?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Playing with pointers in c++. I have come across something unexpected. I have the code:

```
int main(){
  char p=0;
  char* ptr=&p;
  cout<<"This is the pointer: "<<ptr;
return 0;
}
```

When I run this code the output of `ptr` is blank. If I change the value of `p` to any other value it seems to output a random pointer, e.g. value changes between runs, as I would expect. The question then is what is different about assigning a char value to 0.
Extra info: compiling with g++ 4.8.4

Comment: I don't believe you are really seeing a random pointer when you change it from 0, I think you are likely seeing random data from the stack. `cout` treats a `char*` as a null terminated string with the first character being p. When that first character is ` '\0' `, it is an empty string.

Comment: Specifically, `(char)0` (number cast to character, usually its ASCII value) is not the same as `'0'` (the ASCII character zero, decimal 48) is not the same as `"0"` (an anonymous string containing an ASCII zero and a null terminator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char p=0;
```

Your variable is defined as character and assigned an integer value zero, so internally you are assigning a null terminated character on variable p.
If you correct above statement as follows and print more details it may be clear to you.

```
char p='0'; 

std::cout<<"This is the pointer: "<<&ptr<<" ---"<<*ptr <<"----"<<ptr;
```

&&ptr- >  getting the address of ptr

*ptr-> getting the value assigned to the ptr

ptr-> getting the string from ptr until it see a null terminating character, so expects garbage value as output.

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d134412490ca59a

Comment: This is the clearest answer. Just note @jmc comment to question which explains most succinctly explains why I see the empty string printed using the original code from my question.

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behaviour in case when `p` is not set to 0. To make it well-formed write

```
int main(){
  char p=0;
  char* ptr=&p;
  cout<<"This is the character: ";
  //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 
  cout.write( ptr, 1 );
return 0;
}
```

Or

```
int main(){
  char p=0;
  char* ptr=&p;
  cout<<"This is the pointer: "<<( const void * )ptr;
return 0;
}
```

Otherwise this statement

```
  cout<<"This is the pointer: "<< ptr;
```

simply outputs an empty string only when p is set to 0.. In other cases it will output some garbage after character p until a zero character is encountered.

Another approach can look like

```
int main(){
  char p[2]= { 0 };
  char* ptr=&p;
  cout<<"This is the pointer: "<< ptr;
return 0;
}
```

This statement

```
cout<<"This is the pointer: "<< ptr;
```

outputs the string pointed to by ptr. A  string is a sequence of characters terminated with zero character. So you should define a character array with at least two characters where the second character will be always set to 0.

Comment: It's not undefined behavior, he's just printing a zero-length string.

Comment: @Matteo Italia  I mean  that he changes the value in p.:)

Comment: Maybe you should make it more clear (specifying that for a `char *` the relevant `operator<<` overload expects a nul-terminated string, and that in this case it works "by chance" due to the fact that blah blah blah).

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer is pointing to a char which has a value of zero.

The pointer is perfectly valid.

cout is printing a zero length string.

Answer (score 0):

```
char p = 0;
char* ptr=&p;
```

here ptr is a pointer of a zero length string. Because it is a char* pointer which point to a zore(\0) which is considered as the end of a string.